# Soap under Java 1.3 with Axis

Tags: web-services, unix, soap, java

I am writing a Java web service for legacy SCO machines (which only have Java 1.3 available). I have been able to get more recently-added XML parsing functions integrated by including the Xerces jar on my classpath. However Java is screaming about not being able to find javax.xml.soap, even though I've got Axis 1.3 and explicitly added axis2-saaj-1.3.jar (which claims to include javax.xml.soap.*)

Nonetheless, it tells me that package javax.xml.soap doesn't exist. I know it wasn't in the SDK under Java 1.3, but a compatible version is on my freaking classpath! Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: Appreciate the sympathy. 

The import for javax.xml.parsers works as long as I have the Xerces library linked IN EXACTLY THE SAME WAY I am trying to link the Axis libraries. I've tried Axis 1.3 and 1.5, separately and together. 

Furthermore the Axis library appears to contain the javax libraries I need. They're laid out slightly different, though. For instance, in the xml-apis.jar (from Xerces) javax.xml.* are packages in the root of the library. However, in the Axis library, they're tucked underneath META-INF.services.. and I obviously need to be doing something else to get at them!

Comment: I was mostly sorry about you having to use Java 1.3.  I remember it totally sucking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the downloaded distribution try using the saaj.jar in that instead of the axis2-saaj-1.3.jar distributable.

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely binding to the library now. However, it claims not to recognize SOAPMessage.getSOAPBody()... It's recognizing all the other Soap objects and calls -- any idea why this one gives me trouble? (It's after I've received the message and am parsing it to check for faults.)

Comment: Sorry, no clue there.  I fiddled around with Axis 1 a long time ago, but nothing in detail.